# Webbrowser control not playing youtube videos

Tags: wpf, youtube, browser, autoplay

There's a new problem playing back YouTube videos on a WPF WebBrowser control

```
<Window x:Class="plainYoutubeBrowser.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<WebBrowser Name="g_browser"/>
</Window>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g_browser.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9k-k8609go");
    }
}
```

Normally this URL will work in IE and other browsers without issue.

The problem is that the video playback is not started automatically when the page is loaded (you'll see a play icon instead which you'll have to click on).

I added the querystring parameter `&autoplay=1`, but it didn't help.

How can this be solved?

Comment: My guess: it's because the webbrowser control does not have plugin for flash or html5.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's something in the YouTube javascript/flash that changes it's behavior based on the user agent, the referrer field, or the DOM.  Maybe it thinks it's embedded in an IFrame and that autoplay isn't desired.

I'd try to figure out how to manually trigger the play by doing `g_browser.InvokeScript();`

Maybe also see if you can get find a URL to make youtube to go into html5 mode and avoid using flash.

Comment: i've tried switching to html5 using url:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9k-k8609go&html5=True
but it didn't work for me :(

i've also inspected all the source and it seems that there are no method to invoke using invokeScript() method.

this is pretty weird, it use to work fine before google messed things up :\

Comment: Check this for info on their JavaScript API. http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Comment: the java script api is being used when developers want to interact with youtube player (this creates an object by the hosting site code - but not in google native youtube.com site). if you'll use this code (the enable jspi switch) this perticular video wont load on error 150\151\... (because vevo dont allow this clip to be embedded and interacted via javascript). still not working!